# Action sheet UIButton to process delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, cell, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UITableView in which I have files downloaded to from a UIWebView. Before my changes I had no issues deleting the row and from the local folder in which it was downloaded to.

Since then I have implemented a multi select function. Pressing edit, selecting w/e files, pressing delete to show the action sheet works fine. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to make the action sheet process the delete action.

Below I will post the code I'm working with.

```
//viewDidLoad:
self.deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(deleteButton:)];

- (void)deleteButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *actionTitle = ([[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count] == 1) ?
    @"Are you sure you want to remove this item?" : @"Are you sure you want to remove these items?";
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:actionTitle delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

        NSString *fileName = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *path;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *error;

    //Remove cell
        [directoryContents removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        //[tableView reloadData];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])     //Does file exist?
        {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])   //Delete it
            {
                NSLog(@"Delete file error: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any info on how to link that "OK" button to finish the delete would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the UIActionSheet Delegate methods

```
actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

will work perfectly

EDIT

Adding `setEditing:YES` inside the UIActionSheet delegate method will only place the tableView into editing mode, not commit the deletion. I don't know how you are retrieving the rows you wish to delete, but Editing mode only allows a single row selection.

I think what may be better for what you wish to accomplish is manipulate your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to mark each row for deletion, and either add the selected indices to an array, or mark the rows with a checkmark.

Then in the `UIActionSheet` delegate method when the users hits 'OK', place the deletion logic, either use the indices array or iterate through the cells to find the ones you selected for deletion.

I would try this because, as you have experienced, a custom delete button and the `commitEditingStyle` protocol method are difficult to link up because of how this method is invoked.

Comment: I have no issues calling the action sheet, as stated that part works fine. It's linking the action sheet button with the commitEditingStyle to finish the delete process.

Comment: I would perform your delete inside the actionSheet delegate method, and then reload your tableView.

Comment: I believe I just need a way to call the deleteButton id inside the commitEditingStyle like the answer above yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.destructiveButtonIndex) 
      {
              //Delete
              [yourCell setEditing:YES animated:YES];

      }
}
```

Comment: I had to go to work before I could test. I will test later and report back.

Comment: Ok just got home and tried it, I can't seem to manage to link the deleteButton id to the commitEditingStyle.